# Geoserver Seed Problem ( die after submit )

Tags: geoserver

I'm having a problem with seed/truncate on geoserver...
I have a custum gridset "EPSG:900913" but with just the first 20 zoom levels...
And i have some layer's (30) and some MrSid's (160) with this cache options:

[image]

The Problem is, when a try to seed:

[image]

I get this:

```
2015-11-23 11:07:09,338 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-13 begins seeding layer : p:Saneamento_ETAR
2015-11-23 11:07:09,340 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2015-11-23 11:07:09,364 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Width = 256
    Height = 512
    StyleBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    StyleVersion = null
    ScaleMethod = null
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    Tiled = false
    Palette = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    SRS = EPSG:900913
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=p_Saneamento_ETAR]]
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@a9b8a7a1]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-2.003750834E7 : 0.0, -2.003750834E7 : 2.003750834E7]
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Env = {}
    FormatOptions = {}
    Angle = 0.0
    CQLFilter = null
    Elevation = []
    FeatureId = null
    StartIndex = null
    ViewParams = null
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Transparent = true
    StyleFormat = sld
    SldBody = null
    ValidateSchema = false
    Sld = null
    StyleUrl = null
    TilesOrigin = null
    Interpolations = []
    Format = image/png
    Buffer = 0
    Time = []
    Filter = null
    Filters = null
    Get = true
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    RawKvp = {BBOX=-20037508.34,-20037508.34,0.0,20037508.34, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=512, REQUEST=GetMap, STYLES=p_Saneamento_ETAR, WIDTH=256, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, TRANSPARENT=true, VERSION=1.1.1, FORMAT=image/png, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, LAYERS=p:Saneamento_ETAR, SRS=EPSG:900913}
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Version = 1.1.1
    Request = GetMap
2015-11-23 11:07:09,370 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2015-11-23 11:07:10,940 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Width = 512
    Height = 768
    StyleBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    StyleVersion = null
    ScaleMethod = null
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    Tiled = false
    Palette = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    SRS = EPSG:900913
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=p_Saneamento_ETAR]]
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@a9b8a7a1]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS84 / Google Mercator", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"], 
  PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["x", EAST], 
  AXIS["y", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-2.003750834E7 : 0.0, -2.003750834E7 : 1.0018754169999998E7]
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Env = {}
    FormatOptions = {}
    Angle = 0.0
    CQLFilter = null
    Elevation = []
    FeatureId = null
    StartIndex = null
    ViewParams = null
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Transparent = true
    StyleFormat = sld
    SldBody = null
    ValidateSchema = false
    Sld = null
    StyleUrl = null
    TilesOrigin = null
    Interpolations = []
    Format = image/png
    Buffer = 0
    Time = []
    Filter = null
    Filters = null
    Get = true
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    RawKvp = {BBOX=-20037508.34,-20037508.34,0.0,10018754.169999998, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=768, REQUEST=GetMap, STYLES=p_Saneamento_ETAR, WIDTH=512, EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, TRANSPARENT=true, VERSION=1.1.1, FORMAT=image/png, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, LAYERS=p:Saneamento_ETAR, SRS=EPSG:900913}
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Version = 1.1.1
    Request = GetMap
2015-11-23 11:07:11,373 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2015-11-23 11:07:12,321 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2015-11-23 11:07:12,322 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished SEED task after 2.984 seconds
2015-11-23 11:07:12,322 ERROR [seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:575)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:764)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected: RenderedImageMap, got null
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:628)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:569)
    ... 9 more
2015-11-23 11:07:26,291 ERROR [geotools.map] - Call MapContent dispose() to prevent memory leaks
```

What can i do?

Comment: Main error is `2015-11-23 11:07:12,321 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` main cure then is to give more memory.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter noted the problem is:

```
2015-11-23 11:07:12,321 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

You need to check the settings of your JVM and adjust the memory settings appropriately depending on how much memory your system has available: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html